# Crash due to SIGABRT on Linux C++ PowerPC

Tags: c++

My program crashes in string assign. I cannot corner down the exact cause of it. Multiple threads execute the same code.

This is my code.

```
 char* cTemp = new char[5];
    memset(cTemp,'\0', 5);
    snprintf(cTemp , 5 , "%04x" , iParameter);
    string sVar1 = cTemp;
    delete[] cTemp;
    if(sVar1 == "0")
    sVar1 = "0000";
    pSharedLib->setVar1(sVar1);
```

The set Function(in shared library)

```
 bool A::setVar1(CString& temp)
    {   
    m_sVar1= temp;
    return true;
    }
```

The crash bt shows the error as

```
#0 0x48194444 in raise () from /lib/libc.so.6
#0 0x48194444 in raise () from /lib/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#1 0x48199694 in abort () from /lib/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#2 0x481d4ecc in ?? () from /lib/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#3 0x481e14d4 in ?? () from /lib/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#4 0x481e32b0 in free () from /lib/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#5 0x480df8b8 in operator delete(void*) () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#6 0x480b136c in std::string::_Rep::_M_destroy(std::allocator<char> const&)
() from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#7 0x480b35f4 in std::string::assign(std::string const&) ()
from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
No symbol table info available.
```

Comment: `string` and `CString` appears to be different types.

Comment: thats a typo sorry....both are string.. I had watered down some of the functions/typedefs to make it simpler!

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any synchronization objects protecting the set of m_sVar1.  You mentioned that setVar1 could be called from multiple threads simultaneously, the threading guarantees for STL don't guarantee that the assignment is safe from multiple threads.

Comment: ya that could be the problem along with the pass by ref which i am doing right now!!! But i wanted to know if this could cause a SIGABRT?

Comment: Sure.  The string::assign is logically "delete string; string = arg;".  If two threads attempt to delete the same chunk of memory (and note that you're crashing in free()), you can corrupt the heap.  In this case it looks like the heap detected the error and called abort() which in turn raised SIGABRT.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the key to this problem is

> Multiple threads execute the same code.

If there's a single string `m_sVar1`, and multiple threads are assigning to it simultaneously, then the chances are rather good that a race condition will lead to corruption. You need to properly protect that variable with a critical section.

Comment: THanks i guess that could be the problem. Let me try to see if the issue gets reproduced again after protecting it with mutex or semaphore!